# Index entries duplicated for captions

Tags: captions, indexing

In document class `book`, and package `caption`, creating index with `makeidx`.
Index entries for the main text and for footnotes collate properly; but those for captions create their own entries.

Example: for the tag `\index{New York!Custom House!\textit{Cartouche}}`, text and footnotes collate properly; but used in a caption, a new entry is created at the third level, and is also out-of-alphabetic-sequence. Note: the top level, and first sub are correct; only the second sub is duplicated.

How to get the caption index entries under the same entry?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is in the fact that a "normal text" appearance of

```
\index{New York!Custom House!\textit{Cartouche}}
```

writes in the `.idx` file a line such as

```
\indexentry{New York!Custom House!\textit{Cartouche}}{1}
```

while the same in the argument of `\caption` will have

```
\indexentry{New York!Custom House!\textit  {Cartouche}}{3}
```

(the numbers will be different for your document). This is due to how LaTeX processes caption texts. You see that the two lines are different and they are actually *very* different to MakeIndex.

There's also a problem in how you write the index annotations: formatting instructions are bound to confuse the collating process by MakeIndex. So use

```
\index{New York!Custom House!Cartouche@\textit{Cartouche}}
```

in normal text and, for the caption, write something like

```
\begin{figure}
...
\caption{A caption telling about \textit{Cartouche}%
  \index{New York!Custom House!Cartouche@\string\textit{Cartouche}}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Good - this works - thanks - lingering problem: this throws the sort ordering off for the third-level. The entries treated as above have their own sort-order. I'm experimenting, but it looks like it is descending alphabetical.

Comment: @calmbob Can you make an example? MakeIndex bases the sorting on what comes before the `@`

Comment: I think I found the flaw in my thinking - I rigorously harmonized use of \textit across all the entries, and all works magically - correctly, that is

Comment: @egreg -- two points: (1) makeindex bases the combining (if not the sorting) on the entire string within the argument of `\index{...}`, and (2) `\protect` will *not* work here -- it will leave a single space after `\textit` (unprotected command gets two spaces as seen in your example) -- so it is absolutely necessary to use `\string`.  very un-latex-y, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative mechanism

An alternative to egreg's solution I was going to post

```
\newcommand\hmm[1]{#1}
```

Then you can use

```
 8\hmm{\index{....}}
```

You could redefine `\index` to always do this, this just always prevents the verbatim nature of `\index` from activating, so you have to be a bit more careful about what you put in the argument, but it does then work consistently in all contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xindy` instead of `makeindex` as an index-processor also solves the problem without the workarounds by @David Carlisle and @egreg.