# Duplicate typeset index entries

Tags: indexing

I want to have an index entry typeset as `$a_\text{T}$`, so I issue the command `\index{at@$a_\text{T}$}`. Each use of this index command creates a separate line in the index. How can I get `\makeindex` to recognize they all reference the same topic?

My index entries look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: I've updated the post to include a screenshot; each double entry comes from the same index commands `\index{at@$a_\text{T}$}` and `\index{an@$a_\text{N}$}`.

Comment: I think what @egreg meant was can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: For solvers: +`\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: @GregH We need some code that shows the problem: I trust you when you say you get duplicate entries, but I can't know how you input them.

Comment: @GregH I'm not able to replicate your situation too. Á, I think that your problem is that you have different number of spaces in the equations. Try `\index{an@$a_\text{N} $}
\index{at@$a_\text{T} $}
\newpage
\index{an@$a_\text{N}$}
\index{at@$a_\text{T}$}`

Comment: Do you have one index call inside the argument to a macro, and one not? (but really you should provide an example document, then we'd see)

Comment: unrelated but you probably want \mathrm{T} not \text

Comment: Just to know: did you delete the temp files and run `makeindex` again?

Comment: Having answered I remembered having answered before, this is probably a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105713/1090 assuming it _is_ the same issue.

Comment: Sorry about the useless pic of the index - an MWE would have been useful. David's answer helped; one index command was inside a complicated command involving TikZ nodes. Putting the `\index{...` after the command solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hard to say as you provided no example but I'd guess you have done this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

zz\index{at@$a_\mathrm{T}$}

zz\mbox{zz\index{at@$a_\mathrm{T}$}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

One argument is read verbatim and the other not, resulting in an `idx` file like

```
\indexentry{at@$a_\mathrm{T}$}{1}
\indexentry{at@$a_\mathrm  {T}$}{1}
```

with different entries. The easiest solution is to wrap both in the same command. If you put `\mbox` (or anything) around the first `\index`  then the index entries are merged.

Comment: I noticed when you add \mbox then the next word doesn't get hyphenated. Maybe this is only happening in my setup but be sure to check it out.

Comment: a "word" has to be preceded by white space to be considered a word to be tried for hyphenation, so `\mbox{} abcdef" would not try hyphenating `abcdef` you can use `\mbox{} \hspace{0pt)abcdef"  for example @MartinMueller

Comment: my problem was that i have the index behind the word: "Romeo\indexentry{Shakespeare!Romeo and Juliet}, a play" when used with mbox. When I would add \hspace{0pt} and have a comma afterwards it would move that comma to the next line.

Comment: @MartinMueller you have never provided any test file so it is hard to guess what you are doing, but a box after a word does not stop hyphenation, just one before, also you can always use \nolinebreak to prevent a break at the 0pt space, but why are you using `\mbox` at all?

Comment: sorry, you're right, I didn't do it properly. I played around with your solution because i have a command \emph{ } within my entry and the whole whitespace-duplicate entries started. but I have it fixed now with splitindex, protected and an additional parenthesis around the \newcommand{\foo}[1]{{\sindex[foo]{#1}} so I just wanted to leave a small comment.