# Eliding premature tokenisation in index macro

Tags: indexing, makeindex, tokenization

I am generating a very large number of index entries containing formatting in a LaTeX document, and some of them are in regions that affect the premature tokenisation of the argument (footnotes, optional argument to `\item`, etc) so that I get two identical-looking entries on the same page in the `.idx` file, one with spaces after the formatting (eg `\textit␣␣{foo}` as well as `\textit{foo}`).

This has been dealt with in a [question on index entries in footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372308/formatted-index-entries-within-footnotes) and a response link to a [question on named indexes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145309/index-in-footnode-different-from-index-in-main-text) but only in the case of multiple indexes (with an optional parameter to the `\index` command).

Is there a way to solve this for a single index? I can't see from the two pages above how to generalize the solution.

[And, incidentally, I would be interested to know where the two bogus spaces actually come from, and why the tokenisation inserts them.]

Comment: `\let\oldindex\index\def\index#1{\oldindex{#1}}` sure this is a duplicate I'll see if I can find

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176445/1090