# Problem with \index command in argument of user-defined command

Tags: indexing

I have a problem using the `\index` command in an argument to a user-defined command. For some reason, the problem only appears when I use the `@` symbol. The following example illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\newcommand\myFoo[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{The first chapter}

\index{one}
\index{\texttt{two}}

\myFoo{\index{one}}
\myFoo{\index{\texttt{two}}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

When I typeset this source code (with the pdflatex and makeindex commands), the index looks like this:

```
two, 1
two, 1

one, 1
```

So, the "two" entry is displayed twice (in typewriter font), the "one" entry is (correctly) only displayed once. The same problem occurs when I use the `@` operator.

The idx file generated by LaTeX is:

```
\indexentry{one}{1}
\indexentry{\texttt{two}}{1}
\indexentry{one}{1}
\indexentry{\texttt  {two}}{1}
```

I guess the problem is caused by these two spaces before the `{` character in the last index entry, but I do not understand why these spaces are there.

Can somebody explain why entries with formatting commands and entries without them give different results here, and suggest a solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm quite sure this is a duplicate, which doesn't mean it's a bad question.

Comment: This is related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88354/index-entries-duplicated-for-captions

Comment: @egreg. I did search for related questions, but I could only find questions about using `\index` in command definitions, not in command arguments. But yes, the question you linked, and especially your answer there, are very helpful. Thanks!