# Conflict between tabu and index when using LaTeX formatting in index

Tags: indexing, tabu

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabu}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

This is the \emph{aaa} variable.\index{aaa variable@\emph{aaa} variable}

\begin{tabu}{l}
\emph{aaa}\index{aaa variable@\emph{aaa} variable}
\end{tabu}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

In this document I use the index string `\index{aaa variable@\emph{aaa} variable}` twice, once outside a `tabu` environment, once inside it. The result is that the generated `.idx` file contains these lines:

```
\indexentry{aaa variable@\emph{aaa} variable}{1}
\indexentry{aaa variable@\emph  {aaa} variable}{1}
```

which means that `\printindex` will print two entries in the index, rather than just one.

What can I do?

**EDIT**

A comment referred me to a related question where a `\string` in front of `\emph` in the `tabu` environment would solve the problem, and indeed it does.

But if I need to use the `tabu*` environment instead of `tabu` this still not works.

Replacing `tabu` with `tabu*` and `\index{aaa variable@\emph{aaa} variable}` with `\index{aaa variable@\string\emph{aaa} variable}` inside the environment, gives me this content in the `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{aaa variable@\emph{aaa} variable}{1}
\indexentry{aaa variable@\string \emph {aaa} variable}{1}
```

Comment: you can see (related) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88354/index-entries-duplicated-for-captions

Comment: Thank you, @touhami. The suggested fix works - sort of. I have updated my question.

Comment: I think the suggested solution in my answer (not egreg's:-) should work here

Comment: Thank you, @DavidCarlisle. I did some experimentation, and for the `tabu*` environment it appears that I need to do both. I need to add `\string` and I need to use your `\hmm` command. Doing just one of them doesn't work. But now I have a solution - so what do I do with this question? If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll acknowledge it.

Comment: well it's probably a duplicate of the other question in that case, maybe you could leave a comment on one or both of the answers there. (It's the same issue and affects any use of `\index` inside the argument of a command, or inside the body of an environment that uses such a command internally (tabu, tabularx, ams alignments, ....)