# \footnote breaks @-constructs in \index

Tags: footnotes, indexing, imakeidx

To index a nontrivial TeX expression `expr`,
we use the command `\index{str@expr}`, where `str` is a simplified (typically plain ASCII) representation of `expr` to be used for sorting.

However, `str@expr` is parsed incorrectly inside a footnote:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\def\gnu{\texttt{Gnu}}
\def\gnat{\texttt{Gnat}}
\begin{document}
Some text\index{Gnu@\gnu}\index{Gnat@\gnat}.

\pagebreak
Some more text\index{Gnu@\gnu}.\footnote
{A footnote.\index{Gnat@\gnat}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This generates the following `.idx` file

```
\indexentry{Gnu@\gnu}{1}
\indexentry{Gnat@\gnat}{1}
\indexentry{Gnu@\gnu}{2}
\indexentry{Gnat@\texttt  {Gnat}}{2}
```

The two index entries for 'Gnat' differ, and therefore `\Gnat` appears
twice in the index, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

How does `\footnote` modify the `\index` command, and what can be done about it?

Comment: This is a known problem due to the fact that when `\index` is in the argument to another command, the special treatment to the argument cannot be performed. It's been in LaTeX from day one. I linked a duplicate (it's about `\caption`, but the phenomenon is the same). For the special case of footnotes, loading the `bigfoot` package solves the issue.

Comment: The solution is duplicate, but not the problem. Only if you know the solution, or if you are operating at a level of abstraction where _footnote_ and _caption_ are essentially the same, the problem asked here may appear to you as a duplicate of the problem solved there.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke I guess the point is that we are talking '`\index` inside an argument' in both cases, and that problem is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not so much a question of the `@` construction, but of expansion of control sequences.  A work around based on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/_Hwo6Hapcng suggests providing a command we can use to protect the backslash in the index entry in the footnote via `\def\indexprotect#1{\string#1}`.  As Ulrike Fischer points out `\string` is already good enough to do that on its own:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\def\gnu{\texttt{Gnu}}
\def\gnat{\texttt{Gnat}}
\begin{document}
Some text\index{Gnu@\gnu}\index{Gnat@\gnat}.

\pagebreak
Some more text\index{Gnu@\gnu}.\footnote
{A footnote.\index{Gnat@\string\gnat}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: And why not `\string` directly?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good point - works fine.  I'll simplify my answer.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88357/4427

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Andrew Swann and @Ulrike Fischer (use `\string` to escape the backslash in `expr`) works fine, but requires repeated effort in all concerned footnotes or captions. Therefore the solution mentioned in the comment by @egreg,

```
\usepackage{bigfoot}
```

which solves the problem once and for all, appears preferable to me.

Comment: While `bigfoot` works fine in the above MWE, it causes serious trouble in my long report: it generates two empty pages at the end of each chapter.